# Glyphicon bootstrap icon won't show

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap

I have a spring boot application and in the resource folder->templates I have my html files, whereas in the static->css are my bootstrap css files.
But the glyphicon icon will no show and throws an error.
What do I do ?

Comment: How about posting your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the fonts in your application. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/